# Change text order in R

Tags: r, text

I have a character column in a data frame that contains two or more phrases, each of these phrases is separated by a `&&`. I would like R to not differentiate between `phrase1 && phrase2` and `phrase2 && phrase1`. Any ideas how I could go about this?

Example of the output I'd like...

```
text = c("a && b", "c && d", "e && f", "d && c", "g && h", "f && e")
desired_result = c("a && b", "c && d", "e && f", "c && d", "g && h", "e && f")
df = data.frame(text, desired_result )
```

Comment: so do you want a third column which states TRUE if both e-f and f-e are same ? what is your expected output?

Comment: the output I'd like is the result column in the data frame I posted above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sapply(strsplit(text, " && "), function(x) paste(sort(x), collapse=" && "))
```

does what you're after. It works by splitting the string before/after the `&&` part, sorting and then pasting back together.